# JS - Query MySQL WHERE col IN array

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT MAX(x.id) as id,
x.name, x.timestamp, x.balance
FROM sheet x
JOIN
    (SELECT p.name,MAX(id) AS max_id, p.rate
    FROM sheet p GROUP BY p.name) y
ON y.max_id = x.id
GROUP BY x.name
```

What is the best practice to query the name that only IN (dynamically):

```
array= ['flake', 'shane', 'klar']
```

I tried something like this with different state of join() in vain:

```
WHERE x.name IN (' + array.join() + ')
```

Comment: This query can probably be optimized. Would you please provide sample data and expected results? Also, which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: No good use in select field list, fields not present in group by clause. MySql doen't recognize this error (get the first row of group) but in other scenarios (DBMS) your query is wrong.

Comment: @JoeTaras. Could you be more specific and tell me what is wrong in my main query (before the where statement)? I'm beginner and the query seems to be able to serve the needs but needs to add the WHERE statement of array.

Comment: @mediaroot: Please add a sample data and your desired result set (as GMB adviced in his comment) so we can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT MAX(x.id) as id,x.name,x.timestamp,x.balance FROM sheet x JOIN (SELECT p.name,MAX(id) AS max_id,p.rate FROM sheet p GROUP BY p.name) y ON y.max_id = x.id WHERE x.name IN ('flake', 'shane', 'klar') GROUP BY x.name
```

Comment: your can do that, but preferably, you can use prepared statements.